# What is the wrong with the following code?

Tags: natural-join

I am trying to  join two sorted array R(Y,Z) and M(X,Y,A)  but the output is coming out wrong,please let me know whats wrong with my code.Thanks!

```
int [][] R = new int[][] 
        { {1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{2,3,4,5},{1,2,4,5},{9,3,1,7},{2,3,8,9},{2,3,4,5}
        };
        int [][] M = new int[][]
                { {1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{2,4,5,6},{2,3,4,5} };
        int[][] Output=new int[4][4];

while(i<R.length && j<M.length )
{
     if(R[i][0]==M[j][1])
     {
         for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
         { Output[k][x]=M[j][x];

     Output[k][3]=R[i][1];
          j++;}
     if(R[i][0]<M[j][1])
        {i++;}

     else if(R[i][0]>M[j][1])
       {j++;}

     }

}
for (int p =0; p< Output.length; p++ )
   {
   for (int l =0 ; l<4;j++)
           System.out.print(Output[p][l]+" ");
   System.out.println();
  }
```

Actually i am not getting any output!The console just runs blank.

Comment: There's no way to understand the code without decent formatting, take it into an editor or IDE and beautify it, and then repost it.

Comment: Also we'd have to know what output you're getting and what output you expect.

Comment: If it's possible, you should try to explain what you are doing on the code that you wrote

Comment: the hard-coded array elements seem suspicious, though without knowing the array declarations we're all just guessing....why don't you just give us the assignment definition?